# As a best practice, what is the maximum information each node should contain?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

As best practice, what is the maximum number of properties should each node contain when designing a graph database in Neo4j?

Comment: This site is geared towards solving specific programming questions, not providing general advice.

Comment: There's simply no right answer to this. Only you can decide how to best model your data. Plus, you're asking this without a single bit of context (it would still be off-topic, but without context, there's no validity to *any* answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In community edition there is a limit of *2^36 to 2^38 depending on property types (maximum ∼ 274 billion, always at least ∼ 68 billion)* properties. See [the docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/2.3.8/capabilities-capacity.html#capabilities-data-size) (I couldn't find this info in 3.x version of the manual, but the limits still stand for community).

Enterprise edition does not have the limit since 3.x. See [this blog post](https://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-3-0-massive-scale-developer-productivity/).

In reality properties [are stored as linked lists](http://www.slideshare.net/thobe/an-overview-of-neo4j-internals#5) in neo4j, which means matching on a property might need to traverse all properties of a node. So if you do a lot of filtering on properties in your queries than you should keep the numbers low - but you will always need to benchmark on your data.